# Special Character and space input removal

Tags: batch-file

I need a way to stop the batch closing when the user inputs a space and special characters e.g. !@#$%^&*(). Btw if your wondering, I'm coding a quiz in batch.

I have been researching and majority of the methods are using the "for" and go something like "for /L %%i in (0.1.255) do". I mainly want one that works for multiple things since it is a quiz and there are multiple questions.

If you are wondering why some of the variables are random it is because that was the only thing I could think of and that variable was not that important.

I have removed some code on the bottom so that i can post snice my code is reasonably long. Another thing while you are looking could you please tell me why when i answer question 8 it breaks. I am probably pushing it, but is there also a better way to do what I'm doing?

here is my code:

```
<!-- : BATCH
    cscript //nologo "%~f0?.wsf"
    @echo off
    title The Quiz of Minecraft
    color 2
    :menu
REM here is my title but it is quite big since its ASCII
    echo 1) Start
    echo 2) Guide
    echo 3) Exit
    set /p lollies=">> "
    if not defined lollies goto menu
    if %lollies% == 1 goto question1
    if %lollies% == 2 goto Guide
    if %lollies% == 3 (goto Exit) else (goto error1)
    set /p score=
    timeout /t 0 /nobreak >nul

    :error1
    cls
    echo Sorry but %lollies% was invalid, please try again!
    set lollies=
    pause
    goto menu

    :Guide
    cls
    echo Enter the number that is before your selection.  --^> 1) ^Start
    echo Would you like to continue? (y/n)
    set /p guider=">> "
    if not defined guider goto Guide
    if /i %guider% == y goto menu
    if /i %guider% == n (goto Guide) else (goto error2)

    :error2
    cls
    echo Sorry but %guider% was invalid, please try again!
    set guider=
    pause
    goto Guide

    :Exit
    cls
    echo Are you sure you want to leave? (y/n)
    set /p leaving=">> "
    if not defined leaving goto Exit
    if /i %leaving% == y goto bye
    if /i %leaving% == n (goto menu) else (goto error3)

    :error3
    cls
    echo Sorry but %leaving% was invalid, please try again!
    set leaving=
    pause
    goto Exit

    :bye
    cls
    echo Goodbye!
    timeout /t 1 /nobreak >nul
    exit

    :Name
    cls
    echo Please type your username below.
    set /p called="Enter Username: "
    if not defined called goto Name
    goto username

    :username
    cls
    echo Welcome %called%! Hope you enjoy!
    timeout /t 2 /nobreak >nul
    goto question1

    :question1
    cls
    echo 1: What year was Minecraft officially released?
    echo 1) 2008    2) 2009
    echo 3) 2010    4) 2011
    set /p answer1="Answer: "
    if not defined answer1 goto Start
    if %answer1% == 1 goto question2_1
    if %answer1% == 2 goto question2_1
    if %answer1% == 3 goto question2_1
    if %answer1% == 4 (goto question2) else (goto invalid1)

    :invalid1
    cls
    echo Sorry but %answer1% was invalid, please try again!
    set answer1=
    pause
    goto question1

    :question2
    set /a score+=1
    cls
    echo 2: What update added the elytra?
    echo 1) 1.16  2) 1.12
    echo 3) 1.9  4) 1.8
    set /p answer2="Answer: "
    if not defined answer2 goto question2
    if %answer2% == 1 goto question3_1
    if %answer2% == 2 goto question3_1
    if %answer2% == 3 goto question3
    if %answer2% == 2 (goto question3_1) else (goto invalid2)

    :invalid2
    cls
    echo Sorry but %answer2% was invalid, please try again!
    set answer2=
    pause
    goto question2

    :question2_1
    cls
    echo 2: What update added the elytra?
    echo 1) 1.16        2) 1.12
    echo 3) 1.9     4) 1.8
    set /p answer2_1="Answer: "
    if not defined answer2_1 goto question2_1
    if %answer2_1% == 1 goto question3_1
    if %answer2_1% == 2 goto question3_1
    if %answer2_1% == 3 goto question3
    if %answer2_1% == 2 (goto question3_1) else (goto invalid2_1)

    :invalid2_1
    cls
    echo Sorry but %answer2_1% was invalid, please try again!
    set answer2_1=
    pause
    goto question2_1

    :question3
    set /a score+=1
    cls
    echo 3: What update was the combat update?
    echo 1) 1.9  2) 1.2
    echo 3) 1.15  4) 1.13
    set /p answer3="Answer: "
    if not defined answer3 goto question3
    if %answer3% == 1 goto question4
    if %answer3% == 2 goto question4_1
    if %answer3% == 3 goto question4_1
    if %answer3% == 4 (goto question4_1) else (goto invalid3)

    :invalid3
    cls
    echo Sorry but %answer3% was invalid, please try again!
    set answer3=
    pause
    goto question3

    :question3_1
    cls
    echo 3: What update was the combat update?
    echo 1) 1.9     2) 1.2
    echo 3) 1.15    4) 1.13
    set /p answer3_1="Answer: "
    if not defined answer3_1 goto question3_1
    if %answer3_1% == 1 goto question4
    if %answer3_1% == 2 goto question4_1
    if %answer3_1% == 3 goto question4_1
    if %answer3_1% == 4 (goto question4_1) else (goto invalid3_1)

    :invalid3_1
    cls
    echo Sorry but %answer3_1% was invalid, please try again!
    set answer3_1=
    pause
    goto question3_1

    :question4
    cls
    echo 4: What mod makes torches work in the off-hand?
    echo 1) Off-hand Torches    2) Dynamic Lighting
    echo 3) Dynamic Lightning   4) Dynamic torches
    set /p answer4="ANswer: "
    if not defined answer4 goto question4
    if %answer4% == 1 goto question5_1
    if %answer4% == 2 goto question5
    if %answer4% == 3 goto question5_1
    if %answer4% == 4 (goto question5_1) else (goto invalid4)

    :invalid4
    cls
    echo Sorry but %answer4% was invalid, please try again!
    set answer4=
    pause
    goto question4

    :question4_1
    cls
    echo 4: What mod makes torches work in the off-hand?
    echo 1) Off-hand Torches    2) Dynamic Lighting
    echo 3) Dynamic Lightning   4) Dynamic torches
    set /p answer4_1="Answer: "
    if not defined answer4_1 goto question4_1
    if %answer4_1% == 1 goto question5_1
    if %answer4_1% == 2 goto question5
    if %answer4_1% == 3 goto question5_1
    if %answer4_1% == 4 (goto question5_1) else (goto invalid4_1)

    :invalid4_1
    cls
    echo Sorry but %answer4_1% was invalid, please try again!
    set answer4_1=
    pause
    goto question4_1

    :question5
    set /a score+=1
    cls
    echo 5: What are they making changes to in the 1.21 update?
    echo 1) The End      2) Villagers
    echo 3) The Nether  4) Combat
    set /p answer5="Answer: "
    if not defined answer5 goto question5
    if %answer5% == 1 goto question6_1
    if %answer5% == 2 goto question6_1
    if %answer5% == 3 goto question6_1
    if %answer5% == 4 (goto question6) else (goto invalid5)

    :invalid5
    cls
    echo Sorry but %answer5% was invalid, please try again!
    set answer5=
    pause
    goto question5

    :question5_1
    cls
    echo 5: What are they making changes to in the 1.21 update?
    echo 1) The End     2) Villagers
    echo 3) The Nether  4) Combat
    set /p answer5_1="Answer: "
    if not defined answer5_1 goto question5_1
    if %answer5_1% == 1 goto question6_1
    if %answer5_1% == 2 goto question6_1
    if %answer5_1% == 3 goto question6_1
    if %answer5_1% == 4 (goto question6) else (goto invalid5_1)

    :invalid5_1
    cls
    echo Sorry but %answer5_1% was invalid, please try again!
    set answer5_1="Answer: "
    pause
    goto question5_1

    :question6
    set /a score+=1
    cls
    echo 6: What mod adds realism to the elytra?
    echo 1) Better Elytra   2) Elytra Physics
    echo 3) Do A Barrel Roll    4) Elytra Remastered
    set /p answer6="Answer: "
    if not defined answer6 goto question6
    if %answer6% == 1 goto question7_1
    if %answer6% == 2 goto question7_1
    if %answer6% == 3 goto question7
    if %answer6% == 4 (goto question7_1) else (goto invalid6)

    :invalid6
    cls
    echo Sorry but %answer6% was invalid, please try again!
    set answer6=
    pause
    goto question6

    :question6_1
    cls
    echo 6: What mod adds realism to the elytra?
    echo 1) Better Elytra       2) Elytra Physics
    echo 3) Do A Barrel Roll    4) Elytra Remastered
    set /p answer6_1="Answer: "
    if not defined answer6_1 goto question6_1
    if %answer6_1% == 1 goto question7_1
    if %answer6_1% == 2 goto question7_1
    if %answer6_1% == 3 goto question7
    if %answer6_1% == 4 (goto question7_1) else (goto invalid6_1)

    :invalid6_1
    cls
    echo Sorry but %answer6_1% was invalid, please try again
    set answer6_1=
    pause
    goto question6_1

    :question7
    set /a score+=1
    cls
    echo 7: What name do you give an illager to make it attack any mob?
    echo 1) Johnny  2) Charlie
    echo 3) Jeff        4) Bob
    set /p answer7="Answer: "
    if not defined answer7 goto question7
    if %answer7% == 1 goto question8
    if %answer7% == 2 goto question8_1
    if %answer7% == 3 goto question8_1
    if %answer7% == 4 (goto question8_1) else (goto invalid7)

    :invalid7
    cls
    echo Sorry but %answer7% was invalid, please try again!
    set answer7=
    pause
    goto question7

    :question7_1
    cls
    echo 7: What name do you give an illager to make it attack any mob?
    echo 1) Johnny  2) Charlie
    echo 3) Jeff    4) Bob
    set /p answer7_1="Answer: "
    if not defined answer7_1 goto question7_1
    if %answer7_1% == 1 goto question8
    if %answer7_1% == 2 goto question8_1
    if %answer7_1% == 3 goto question8_1
    if %answer7_1% == 4 (goto question8_1) else (goto invalid7_1)

    :invalid7_1
    cls
    echo Sorry but %answer7_1% was invalid, please try again!
    set answer7_1=
    pause
    goto question7_1

    :question8
    set /a score+=1
    cls
    echo 8: What is the name for the 1.21 update?
    echo 1) The Bountiful   2) The Frostburn
    echo 3) Trails ^& tails 4) Forrests ^& Fossils
    set /p answer8="Answer: "
    if not defined answer8 goto question8
    if %answer8% == 1 goto question9_1
    if %answer8% == 2 goto question9_1
    if %answer8% == 3 goto question9_1
    if %answer8% == 4 goto (question9) else (goto invalid8)

    :invalid8
    cls
    echo Sorry but %answer8% was invalid, please try again!
    set answer8=
    pause
    goto question8

    :question8_1
    cls
    echo 8: What is the name for the 1.21 update?
    echo 1) The Bountiful   2) The Frostburn
    echo 3) Trails ^& tails 4) Forrests ^& Fossils
    set /p answer8_1="Answer: "
    if not defined answer8_1 goto question8_1
    if %answer8_1% == 1 goto question9_1
    if %answer8_1% == 2 goto question9_1
    if %answer8_1% == 3 goto question9_1
    if %answer8_1% == 4 goto (question9) else (goto invalid8_1)

    :invalid8_1
    cls
    echo Sorry but %answer8_1% was invalid, please try again!
    set answer8_1=
    pause
    goto question8_1

    :question9
    set /a score+=1
    cls
    echo 9: What was the first anarchy server on minecraft?
    echo 1) Arch Haven  2) Chaos Control
    echo 3) 2B2T        4) Nuke Nation
    set /p answer9="Answer: "
    if not defined answer9 goto question9
    if %answer9% == 1 goto question10_1
    if %answer9% == 2 goto question10_1
    if %answer9% == 3 goto question10
    if %answer9% == 4 goto (question10_1) else (goto invalid9)

    :invalid9
    cls
    echo Sorry but %answer9% was invalid, please try again!
    set answer9=
    pause
    goto question9

    :question9_1
    cls
    echo 9: What was the first anarchy server on minecraft?
    echo 1) Arch Haven  2) Chaos Control
    echo 3) 2B2T        4) Nuke Nation
    set /p answer9_1="Answer: "
    if not defined answer9_1 goto question9_1
    if %answer9_1% == 1 goto question10_1
    if %answer9_1% == 2 goto question10_1
    if %answer9_1% == 3 goto question10
    if %answer9_1% == 4 goto (question10_1) else (goto invaild9_1)

    :invalid9_1
    cls
    echo Sorry but %answer9_1% was invalid, please try again!
    set answer9_1=
    pause
    goto question9_1
BATCH : --->

<job><script language="VBScript">

Set WshShell = CreateObject ("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.SendKeys "{f11}"

 </script></job>
REM Review then score:
```

Comment: Search SO (top bar) for `[batch]menu` Don't use `set/p` - use `choice`

Comment: repeating the same or very similar code is just bad. Just by consolidating (and a bit of improvement), I got your script from 413 lines down to 93. The best part: each new question adds just a single line (in comparison to +38 with your approach). Sadly the question got closed just as I formatted my answer.

Comment: By the way: `goto (question9)` is invalid. It should be `(goto question9)`

Comment: @CodeCorruption See [How to stop Windows command interpreter from quitting batch file execution on an incorrect user input?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49834019/3074564)

Answer (score 0):

If you repeat the same (or very similar) portions of your code several times, you have to maintain it in each instance (that is where your original error comes from: in question 8 you messed up the syntax). It is better to consolidate the code so you use a single instance (function) several times.

Also for safe input from the user, `choice` is the command to use (as already suggested in the comments; it does its own error handling and accepts only defined input).

You have a lot of questions (9 in your shortened script), all with four possible answers (same format, which makes it easy to handle them all with the same subroutine AND collect all questions in a single place in the script, which makes it very easy to maintain the code and easily add additional questions.

I kept the general logical flow of your script, just consolidated the repeated code parts (and changed to `choice` and got rid of some now obsolete errorhandling) and added a suggestion of an "end-score message" (feel free to adapt it to your needs, like a stronger malus for wrong answers etc.)

```
<!-- : BATCH
rem @cscript //nologo "%~f0?.wsf"
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
title The Quiz of Minecraft
color 2
:menu
REM here is my title but it is quite big since its ASCII
echo 1) Start
echo 2) Guide
echo 3) Exit
choice /c 123
if errorlevel 3 goto exit
if errorlevel 2 goto guide
if errorlevel 1 goto game
set "score=0" Number of questions answered correct with first try
set "tries=0" Total number of answers given
timeout /t 0 /nobreak >nul

:Guide
cls
echo Enter the number that is before your selection.  --^> 1) Start
echo short description of the goal of this game
pause
goto menu

:Exit
cls
choice /M "Are you sure you want to leave?"
if errorlevel 2 goto menu
echo Goodbye!
timeout /t 1 /nobreak >nul
color
exit /b

:game
cls
echo Please type your username below.
set /p called="Enter Username: "
if not defined called goto game
cls
echo Welcome %called%! Hope you enjoy!
timeout /t 2 /nobreak >nul

for /f %%a in ('findstr /B "Q[1-9][0-9]*:" "%~f0"') do set /a "questions+=1"
for /l %%i in (1,1,%questions%) do call :askQuestion %%i
set /a percent=score*100/tries
echo Thank you for playing, %called%. Questions: %questions%. Tries:%tries%. Score:%percent%%% (first right:%score%)
timeout /t 5 >nul
color
goto :eof

:AskQuestion 
set "first="
:AskAgain
for /f "tokens=1-7 delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /b "Q%1:" "%~f0"') do (
  echo Question %1: %%b?  [DBG: %%g]
  echo 1^) %%c
  echo 2^) %%d
  echo 3^) %%e
  echo 4^) %%f
  choice /c 1234 /M "Your answer? "
  if !errorlevel! == %%g (
    set /a tries+=1
    if not defined first set /a score+=1 
    echo correct.
  ) else (
    set /a tries+=1
    set first=false 
    echo incorrect.
    goto :askAgain %1
  )
)
goto :eof

REM Q/A section. Format: Number:question:answer1:answer2:answer3:answer4:correctAnswer
Q1:What year was Minecraft officially released:2008:2009:2010:2011:4
Q2:What update added the elytra:1.16:1.12:1.9:1.8:3
Q3:What update was the combat update:1.9:1.2:1.15:1.13:4
Q4:What mod makes torches work in the off-hand:Off-hand torches:Dynamic Lighting:Dynamic Lightning:Dynamic torches:2
Q5:What are they making changes to in the 1.21 update:The End:villagers:The Nether:Combat:4
Q6:What mod adds realism to the elytra:Better Elytra:Elytra Physics:Do A Barrel Roll:Elytra Remastered:3
Q7:What name do you give an villager to make it attack any mob:Johnny:Charlie:Jeff:Bob:1
Q8:What is the name for the 1.21 update:The Bountiful:The Frostburn:Trails & tails:Forrests & Fossils:4
Q9:What was the first anarchy server on minecraft:Arch Haven:Chaos Control:2B2T:Nuke Nation:3

BATCH : --->
<job><script language="VBScript">
Set WshShell = CreateObject ("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.SendKeys "{f11}"
</script></job>
```

The `for /f %%a ...` line counts the number of questions rather than hardcoding it, making it very easy to remove or add questions without changing the code itself.

(Note: remove `[DBG: %%g]` after testing. It was the only way for me to give correct answers during troubleshooting)

Comment: Thank you guys so much! I will take all of this information onboard and better improve my coding skills! I couldn't have done it without you!

Comment: When you just started, consider changing to PowerShell. It's a very powerful and well-designed language (and even working on Linux and MacOS). Batch is depreciated and evolved by just inconsistently adding things to its roots that date back to the early nineteen-eighties (or even back to 1974 - depending on how you look at it)

Comment: How would I do that? (I'm on Windows 11)

Comment: How would you do what? Changing to Powershell? `[Alt]-[R]`, `Powershell`. Use Google (or *any* search machine) to look for Powershell tutorials. Also [SS64](https://ss64.com/ps/) is a good resource (and of course [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powershell))